# Why in $3x+5y=a$ every $0\ge a \ne 1, 2, 4, 7$ is possible?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Ex.6 Ch.6 of the book A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory by J.H.Silverman asks :

> Make a list of some of the numbers of the form $3x + 5y$ with $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$. Make 
>   a conjecture as to which values are not possible. Then prove that your conjecture is 
>   correct.

Two questions arises: I made a long list of integers for different values of $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$. It seems that the only values of $a$ for which $3x + 5y = a$ has no solutions in $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$ are $a=1, 2, 4, 7$. **Q.1-** A naive approach : For each of those values it is easy to prove that $3x + 5y = a$ has no solutions in $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$; because, if $3x + 5y = 1$ then solutions are $(x,y)= (-3+5k, 2-3k)$, so no matter what integer is chosen for $k$, it is not possible that both $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$. Same argument for $a=2,4,7$, becasue for example if $a=7$ then $(x',y') = 7(x,y)= (-21+35k, 14-21k)$ won't result in nonnegative solutions. -|-|- But the problem is that it says same that there must not be solutions for $a=8$ as well. And the bigger problem is that if a solution exists for $a=8$, it must be of of the form $8(-3+5k, 2-3k)$ since $\gcd (3,5)=1$ and the book proves that *all* solutions are of the form $(-3+5k, 2-3k)$ for some $k$; so for $a=8$ they must just be multiplied by $8$. (?)

On the other hand, **Q.2-** I can't *prove* why for any nonnegative value other than $a=1, 2, 4, 7$, why there exists always a pair of $(x,y)$ both nonnegative.

Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $(x,y) = (1,1),(3,0),(0,2)$ gives $a=8,9,10$, any $a= 8+3k+t$ with $0\leq t \leq 2$ can be derived by \begin{equation} \begin{split}&t=0: \ \ \ (x,y)=(1+k,1)\ \ \ \ \\&t=1: \ \ \ (x,y)=(3+k,0)\ \ \ \ \\&t=2: \ \ \ (x,y)=(k,2)\ \ \ \ \end{split}\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

Chicken Mcnugget Theorem.

When you have $ax+by=m$, there are exactly $\frac{(a-1)(b-1)}{2}$ numbers that cannot be formed, which lines up with the 4 you couldn't form.

The upper bound on these numbers are $ab-a-b$, or $7$.

Straight from here: http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Chicken_McNugget_Theorem